# Defining and accessing members of unions and structs

Tags: c++, struct, union

I've got three possible definitions, but I'm confused why there are so many.
Does accessing the members behave any different than one over the other?
What are the pros and cons? Just wondering if there are some rules to consider before using any of these.

For `a`,`r`,`g`,`b`,`color`, I want to access the components in memory based on the datatype, or retrieve the `unsigned int` of the `color` at the same memory location.

```
struct RGBColor
{
    union
    {
        BYTE a, r, g, b;
        UINT color;
    };
};
```

```
struct RGBColor2
{
    union { BYTE a, r, g, b; };
    union { UINT color; };
};
```

```
union RGBColor3
{
    struct { BYTE a, r, g, b; };
    struct { UINT color; };
};
```

I tried to look for a simple answer, but couldn't find any.

Comment: `union { BYTE a, r, g, b; };` doesn't feel right. That's a union of *either* alpha, red, green or blue. Similarly with the first union.

Comment: Natural Number Guy, "Does accessing the members behave any different than one over the other? " --> Yes.  " What are the pros and cons, just wondering if there are some rules to consider before using any of these." --> Depends on your unstated coding goals.  Except `struct RGBColor2` is weird.

Comment: And in a C++ union, you can only read from the last member you wrote to. C++ doesn't allow type-punning. So if you plan on setting the individual channels, and read out their "color" value (or the opposite), it will not work.. Not to mention that different systems might have different byte-order, making it all non-portable. You need to come up with a different solution altogether.

Comment: It is undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union.

Comment: Better store just a `uint32_t` and write setters/getters for the a,r,g,b, components.

Comment: @Ripi2 Using simple shift and mask operations.

Comment: I forgot one thing. Maybe one could use bitfields for getting the channels? Bitfields in combination with union or structs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood how unions work. The first struct contains a union with five alternatives: A byte named a, a byte named r, and so on.

The second struct contains two unions. The first contains one of four bytes, but only one at a time, and the second always contains a uint.

The third is a proper union. It either contains a struct of four bytes or a struct containing a Color. Now I don’t know what your plans are, but storing four bytes into the first alternative and reading them as a Color is undefined behaviour. What’s worse, it’s the kind of undefined behaviour that “works” on some compilers but not on others. Or worse, in a development version but not a released version.

(How would undefined behaviour not “work”? Say you wrote a zero into the Color. Then you write a, r,g and b and read the Color. Compiler says “you wrote 0 to Color, you didn’t write anything else to Color, therefore the Color must be 0”. Or the compiler says “you write a, r, g and b, then read Color. That’s undefined behaviour, so I remove the four byte stores”.)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have suggested (I can't comment, I don't have the rep), the "disadvantages" of struct RGBColor and struct RGBColor2 are that they are probably not what you want. Consider that they could be written as

```
struct RGBColor
{
    union
    {
        BYTE a;
        BYTE r;
        BYTE g;
        BYTE b;
        UINT color;
    };
};
```

and

```
struct RGBColor2
{
    union {
        BYTE a;
        BYTE r;
        BYTE g;
        BYTE b;
    };
    union { UINT color; };
};
```

so RGBColor will let you access a or r or g or b or colour, and RGBColor2 will let you access a or r or g or b and colour. A union with one member (as the second field, UINT color, of RGBColor2) is essentially redundant, as it just means the the field.

The third version, RGBColor3, would do what you require, although, as also pointed out, UINT could be any size depending on the target architecture, so uint32_t, from stdint.h, would be better, as it is guaranteed to be 4 bytes,. If we're going to use stdint.h, I'd also use uint8_t for the bytes to be consistent. Also, the struct with one field, like a union with one field, is redundant, so could probably be better represented as

```
union RGBColor3 {
    struct {
        uint8_t a;
        uint8_t r;
        uint8_t g;
        uint8_t b;
    };
    uint32_t color;
};
```

which would allow you to access the four bytes of color either individually, or as a 32 bit value.

Comment: The last sentence unfortunately needs a "sometimes."